# Android Canvas drawText with SpannableString

Tags: android, canvas, spannablestring

I made a custom `View` using `Canvas.drawText()` to draw some `SpannableString`s.

I call `SpannableString.setSpan()` when the text contains emoji I made(I don't like the default-style emoji). 
I found the `Canvas.drawText()` does not draw the span I set and instead, it draws the default-style emoji.
I tried to call `TextView.setText()` passing the same `SpannableString` and it works.
I want to use `Canvas` to draw the text for performance(Otherwise, newing several `TextView`s while scrolling in `ListView` causes severe problem about performance). How can I draw `SpannableString` with `Canvas`?

Sorry for my poor English, I am not a native speaker. Thanks for advance!

EDIT: Actually I made this custom `View` in order to show animation of text transitions. Several texts will go across the screen horizontally. The problem I met is that the `TextView`'s draw method causes too much time and the animation looks bad. So I want to draw the text directly using `Canvas`. Sadly, I switched to `StaticLayout` and still found the animation is jerky.

Comment: @pskink It's still slow in some circumstance. I used `drawText` and `drawBitmap` instead. It worked, but I wonder if my solution is elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding your `Spannable` to a `StaticLayout` and draw that to a `Canvas`.

Something like this:

```
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(yourSpannable, yourPaint,
        yourCanvas.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
layout.draw(yourCanvas);
```